# How do i run this activity only once?

Tags: java, android

There is an activity named **permissions** in my app, and I want it to run only once because it is an activity where users allow permissions for the app, and once they are allowed there is no need for this activity. Now i am able to activity after permissions are granted by user but the problem is when i am on main activity and press back button i still see permissions activity. I dont want to show permissions on back press button

The relevant Java code is below:

```js
package com.techjapreet.shivshankarkiringtone;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

public class permissions extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int WRITE_STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 123;
    private static final int WRITE_SETTINGS_REQUEST_CODE = 321;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.permissions);

        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String FirstTime = preferences.getString("FirstTimeInstall", "");

        if(FirstTime.equals("Yes")){
            Intent intent = new Intent(permissions.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putString("FirstTimeInstall", "Yes");
            editor.apply();

        }





        findViewById(R.id.btn_do_task).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                                                              @Override
                                                              public void onClick(View v) {
                                                                  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                                                      if (checkBoth()) {
                                                                          startActivity(new Intent(permissions.this, MainActivity.class));
                                                                      }
                                                                      else {
                                                                          checkStoragePermission();
                                                                      }
                                                                  }
                                                              }
                                                          }
        );
    }

    private boolean checkBoth() {
        return (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) && Settings.System.canWrite(this);
    }

    public void checkStoragePermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                    this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setMessage("Ringtone, Read External and Write External" +
                        " Storage permissions are required to do the task.");
                builder.setTitle("Please Grant those Permissions");
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                                permissions.this,
                                new String[]{ Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE },
                                WRITE_STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE
                        );
                    }
                });
                builder.setNeutralButton("Cancel", null);
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
            }
            else {
                // Directly request for required permissions, without explanation
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                        this,
                        new String[]{ Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE },
                        WRITE_STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE
                );
            }
        }
        else {
            // Do something, when permissions are already granted
            Toast.makeText(this, "Write External Storage Permission Already Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (checkBoth()) {
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
            }
            else {
                checkSettingsPermission();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case WRITE_STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE:
                // When request is cancelled, the results array are empty
                if ((grantResults.length > 0) && (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                    // Permissions are granted
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Write External Storage Permission Granted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    // Permissions are denied
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Write External Storage Permission Denied.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
        }

        if (checkBoth()) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        }
        else {
            checkSettingsPermission();
        }
    }

    private void checkSettingsPermission() {
        if (!Settings.System.canWrite(this)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
            startActivityForResult(intent, WRITE_SETTINGS_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case WRITE_SETTINGS_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (Settings.System.canWrite(this)) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Write Settings Permission Granted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Write Settings Permission Denied.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
        }
        if (checkBoth()) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Is it the Launcher activity or you route to it using `startActivity`?

Comment: I think a simple flag will be enough for this situation. You can persist this flag once you are done with the said activity and use it for future purposes.

Comment: i want to show permission.java activity only one time to a user because when the permissions are granted there is no use of it so i want the user to directly go to main activity after permissions are granted

Comment: @Mahdi-Malv HI sir now i have edited my code and Now i am able to activity after permissions are granted by user but the problem is when i am on main activity and press back button i still see permissions activity. I dont want to show permissions on back press button

Comment: Simply call `finish()` after starting activity if you want the activity to be removed from stack.

Comment: @Jaspreetsingh `because when the permissions are granted there is no use of it ` this approach is actually wrong since the user may revoke any permission at any time.  You should always check for permission before accessing protected API, for best practices see https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/runtime-permissions

Comment: how can i do that could you please tell me by providing a code and where to place it

Comment: @Mahdi-Malv by adding finish i still se permissions activity on back button press

Comment: If you call finish on an activity when starting a new one, it will close the activity. If you get back, it depends one the `onBackPressed` then. If you start activity, it will start, other wise it will pop from stack which the permissions is not a member of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add method `onPause` to your class:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
```

when click on back (physical or virtual) never show again this activity.

and to next run, you need to  save state in `file` or `shared-preferences` and check it when is true start another activity

```
if (isCheckAcceptAgrement){
   startactivity(this, anotherActivity.class);
}else{
   startactivity(this, acceptAgrement.class);
}
```

Comment: Now i am able to activity after permissions are granted by user but the problem is when i am on main activity and press back button i still see permissions activity. I dont want to show permissions on back press button

Answer (score 1):

### Reason of the issue

This is because the activity is open in the memory, you are just starting the main activity without destroying the permission activity. So, when you are pressing the back button the previous activity loads as it was just on a paused state.

---

### Solution

To destroy the activity from the memory, just do this...

> Add the line **>>>** **`finish()`** after everytime you are typing this line **>>>**  **`startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));`**

Comment: Welcome. Happy to help!

Comment: Just in case if your problem was successfully solved by any answer, you can mark them as **accepted** which will even help other people to find the correct solution of the particular problem. Thanks!